# Replacing current software

Tags: system-installation

If I replace my current software (Windows 7) will I lose all of my music, videos etc. Also will I be able to download iTunes on ubuntu? or what other software can I use for my iPhone?

Comment: If your data matters to you **Back it Up**. External drives are not expensive and while it should be possible to install Ubuntu without losing data its better to be safe than sorry. Apple are not interested in supporting Ubuntu (or any Linux) they want you to buy a Mac.  They only support Windows because the market is too big to ignore; so iTunes will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you install to another partition you can retrieve the files, but your programs will not "reinstall" or simply be there when you install. Also, make sure you install to another partition, otherwise it will overwrite the files from the windows installation. I do not think itunes is compatible, but so long as you can mount the ipod as mass storage you can put the files on it manually

Comment: iTunes appears to be 'mediocre' with [WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347). I'll also add on, be sure to resize your partitions through Windows rather than through the ubuntu installer - I've lost data by not doing that before.

Comment: How do I create another partition? I've been trying to dual boot the software but every time it tells me to select a partition or create one it never wors

Comment: Also to Musher how do I re-size my partitions?

Comment: boot the live environment and start gparted, resize the windows partition and then create an ext4 partition in the empty space